# $.ajax accessing outside variable in success:

Tags: javascript, jquery

As title in example:

*Outside of tabify():*

```
var abc=1;  //pass from here
```

*This part was calling in tabify():*

```
$.ajax({

success:
        //get abc here if possible???
});
```

Is there by any chance to reach var abc when it is outside of $.ajax() ?
Failed to access still don't know where to debug...

Comment: Um, have you tried it? That should work just fine. If it doesn't, you need to post more code.

Comment: lonesomeday, I tried but can't get the abc.
Matthew, what u mean by closure?

Comment: You have to provide some more code. We cannot see in which scopes `abc` and the ajax call are. Regarding closures:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just use it, and don't override it with another version with a narrower scope.

Comment: David, I have edited the top slightly to a more detail happening. But it seems failed to access.